# Error, Char Array showing 11 chars not 12

Tags: arrays, string, char, arduino

I have written a program on the arduino to store 12 characters to char array from a string, but only 11 seem to have been copied.  Here is the code:

```
const int NUMBER_OF_TAGS = 8;
const int TYPE_MASTER = 0;
typedef struct
{
    char TAG[12];
    byte TagType;
} stTAGdef;

stTAGdef Libary[NUMBER_OF_TAGS + 2] ; //(0 to 9)

void setup()
{
    AddTag("4D0055754A27", 0, TYPE_MASTER);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
        int i=0;
        String sDisplay(Libary[i].TAG);
        /*Here it only prints 11 chars not 12*/
        Serial.print(Libary[i].TAG);
        while (1){}
}
void AddTag(String TAG, int Location, int tt)
{
    TAG.toCharArray(Libary[Location].TAG, 12);
    Libary[Location].TagType = (byte)tt;
}
```

Online version: https://codebender.cc/sketch:97071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember that char-array-based strings are null-terminated (so their last character is a '\0'.

I suppose that Arduino already knows this, so it fills the buffer until he has space, then stops converting.

What should you do? That's easy: use a 12+1 bytes buffer.

Or, if you are forced to have a 12 bytes buffer, don't use the toCharArray function but copy it one-by-one.